# Simple integer operation calculator

Tags: code-golf, math, number, arithmetic

### Implement a simple integer operation scriptable calculator.

**Concept**

The accumulator starts at 0 and has operations performed on it. At the end of the program output the value of the accumulator.

**Operations:**

- `+` adds `1` to the accumulator
- `-` subtracts `1` from the accumulator
- `*` multiplies the accumulator by `2`
- `/` divides the accumulator by `2`

**Sample script**

The input `++**--/` should give the output `3`.

**Example implementation**

```
def calc(s)
    i = 0
    s.chars.each do |o|
        case o
            when '+'
                i += 1
            when '-'
                i -= 1
            when '*'
                i *= 2
            when '/'
                i /= 2
        end
    end
    return i
end
```

### Rules

- This is [code-golf](/questions/tagged/code-golf), so lowest answer in bytes wins, but is not selected.
- Creative implementations are encouraged.
- Standard loopholes are prohibited.
- You get the program via stdin or arguments, and you can output the answer via return value or stdout.
- Have fun.
- Division truncates down because it is integer division.
- The program `-/` returns `-1`.

**Test cases**

```
*///*-*+-+
-1
/*+/*+++/*///*/+-+//*+-+-/----*-*-+++*+**+/*--///+*-/+//*//-+++--++/-**--/+--/*-/+*//*+-*-*/*+*+/+*-
-17 
+++-+--/-*/---++/-+*-//+/++-*--+*+/*/*/++--++-+//++--*/***-*+++--+-*//-*/+*/+-*++**+--*/*//-*--**-/-*+**-/*-**/*+*-*/--+/+/+//-+*/---///+**////-*//+-+-/+--/**///*+//+++/+*++**++//**+**+-*/+/*/*++-/+**+--+*++++/-*-/*+--/++*/-++/-**++++/-/+/--*/-/+---**//*///-//*+-*----+//--/-/+*/-+++-+*-*+*+-/-//*-//+/*-+//+/+/*-/-/+//+**/-****/-**-//+/+-+/*-+*++*/-/++*/-//*--+*--/-+-+/+/**/-***+/-/++-++*+*-+*+*-+-//+/-++*+/*//*-+/+*/-+/-/*/-/-+*+**/*//*+/+---+*+++*+/+-**/-+-/+*---/-*+/-++*//*/-+-*+--**/-////*/--/*--//-**/*++*+/*+/-+/--**/*-+*+/+-*+*+--*///+-++/+//+*/-+/**--//*/+++/*+*////+-*-//--*+/*/-+**/*//+*+-//+--+*-+/-**-*/+//*+---*+//*/+**/*--/--+/*-*+*++--*+//+*+-++--+-*-*-+--**+/+*-/+*+-/---+-*+-+-/++/+*///*/*-+-*//-+-++/++/*/-++/**--+-////-//+/*//+**/*+-+/+/+///*+*///*-/+/*/-//-*-**//-/-+--+/-*--+-++**++//*--/*++--*-/-///-+/+//--+*//-**-/*-*/+*/-*-*//--++*//-*/++//+/-++-+-*/*-+++**-/-*++++**+-+++-+-***-+//+-/**-+/*+****-*+++*/-*-/***/-/*+/*****++*+/-/-**-+-*-*-++**/*+-/*-+*++-/+/-++*-/*-****-*
18773342
```

Comment: So... it's not strictly integer, since `/` can yield non-integers.

Comment: Then you should specify this explicitly.

Comment: What should `-/` return?

Comment: @Dennis Well, C truncation says it should round to 0, so that should be `0`...

Comment: @LegionMammal978 Yet the [reference implementation](http://ideone.com/fWX9fp) returns **-1**.

Comment: I can't help but notice that the snippet of code featured on the home page of rust-lang solves this challenge.

Comment: @Zwei That's exactly where I got this challenge.

Comment: My recursive solution returns an floating point number. Is this allowed? The results are correct, but they contain `.0` at the end.

Comment: Does the program have to handle the empty input string ?

Comment: Please add more test cases.

Comment: Curse that nasty round-down requirement!  I had a nice 41-byte GNU sed + dc answer: `s/[+-]/1&/g;s/[*/]/2&/g;s/.*/dc -e 0d&p/e`, but it rounds towards zero when you divide a negative  :-(

Comment: May we substitute the symbols with `+-×÷` or 'PMTD'?

Comment: @TobySpeight you can divide this way in dc to have the desired rounding: `[1-]S@d0>@2/`, because the default output precision is 0 (see [my answer](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/91476/simple-integer-operation-calculator/91514#91514))

Comment: @TonHospel It outputs 0 because the accumulator starts at 0 and changes only with operations.

Comment: @MartinEnder xnor did that for me

Comment: @Adám no, they must be exactly as specified. Sorry.

Answer (score 28):

### Python 2, 48 bytes

```python
i=0
for c in input():exec"i=i%s2&-2"%c
print i/2
```

Does `+2`, `-2`, `*2`, or `/2`. By doing `+2` and `-2` rather than `+1` and `-1`, we're working in doubled units, so the final output needs to be halved. Except, the floor-division `/` now needs to round down to a multiple of 2, which is done with `&-2`.

Comment: This is brilliant! If you want to post it yourself a  CJam port of this would currently be leading the challenge: `0q{2\~-2&}/2/` (`2\~` evals the operator with second operand `2`, `-2&` is the bitwise AND, `2/` is the final division by two. `q{...}/` is a foreach over the input and `0` is just the initial value.)

Comment: You can post it, I don't know CJam.

Comment: Really clever! Ported to ES6 this would easily outperform my answer

Comment: Brilliant use of python. Learned something new from this.

Answer (score 12):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), <s>18</s> 17 [bytes](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly/wiki/Code-page)

```
‘

’

:2
Ḥ
O0;ṛĿ/
```

[Try it online!](http://jelly.tryitonline.net/#code=4oCYCgrigJkKCjoyCuG4pApPMDvhuZvEvy8&input=&args=KysqKi0tLw)

#### How it works

The first six lines define helper links with indices ranging from **1** to **6**; they increment, do nothing, decrement, do nothing, halve (flooring), and double.

The main link – `O0;ṛĿ/` – converts the input characters to their code points (`O`), prepends a **0** (initial value) to the array of code points `0;`, then reduces the generated array as follows.

The initial value is the first element of the array, i.e., the prepended **0**. The quicklink `ṛĿ` is called for every following element in the array, with the last return value as left argument and the current element as right one. It inspects its right argument (`ṛ`) and evaluates the link with that index monadically (`Ŀ`), thus applying the desired operation.

Comment: This looks like the jelly answer with the most newlines

Answer (score 12):

### Haskell, 51 bytes

```
x#'+'=x+1
x#'-'=x-1
x#'*'=x*2
x#_=div x 2 
foldl(#)0
```

Usage example: `foldl(#)0 $ "++**--/"` -> `3`.

Answer (score 10):

## Python 2, 54 bytes

```
i=0
for c in input():exec"i=i"+c+`~ord(c)%5%3`
print i
```

Input is taken as a string literal. `~ord(c)%5%3` maps the operators to the corresponding right operands.

Previously, I used `hash(c)%55%3` which didn't yield consistent results between different versions of Python. This encouraged me to explore other formulas.

Comment: doesn't seem to work...

Comment: 55,3 and 65,4 are the two shortest for double mod of hash in python 2

Comment: @DestructibleWatermelon does for me: [ideone](http://ideone.com/TN4fvt)

Comment: I think `hash` is Python version specific - ideone uses 2.7.10 which gives `[1, 1, 2, 2]` as the four mappings, whereas locally on 2.7.12 I get `[2, 0, 1, 0]`

Comment: it works on ideone, but not on my computers python. Probably version dependent, in which case version should be noted EDIT: ninja'd :/

Comment: @sp3000 I see. I didn't know hash isn't  backwards compatible especially considering such a small difference in versions.

Comment: FWIW, `2-ord(c)%11%3` is only a byte longer and works everywhere.

Comment: @lynn Thanks, you prompted me to look for an even shorter formula that doesn't rely on hash.

Answer (score 10):

## [S.I.L.O.S](https://github.com/rjhunjhunwala/S.I.L.O.S), <s>133</s> 211 bytes

```
:s
def : lbl G GOTO
readIO
i-46
if i a
i+2
if i b
i+2
if i c
i+1
if i d
G e
:a
G v
:p
a-1
a/2
G o
:v
a+1
if a p
a-1
j=a
j/2
k=j
k*2
k-a
a/2
if k t
G o
:t
a-1
:o
G s
:b
a-1
G s
:c
a+1
G s
:d
a*2
G s
:e
printInt a
```

Takes the ASCII codes of operators.

Try it online with test cases:
[`-/`](http://silos.tryitonline.net/#code=OnMKZGVmIDogbGJsIEcgR09UTwpyZWFkSU8KaS00NgppZiBpIGEKaSsyCmlmIGkgYgppKzIKaWYgaSBjCmkrMQppZiBpIGQKRyBlCjphCkcgdgo6cAphLTEKYS8yCkcgbwo6dgphKzEKaWYgYSBwCmEtMQpqPWEKai8yCms9agprKjIKay1hCmEvMgppZiBrIHQKRyBvCmxibHQKYS0xCjpvCkcgcwo6YgphLTEKRyBzCjpjCmErMQpHIHMKOmQKYSoyCkcgcwo6ZQpwcmludEludCBh&input=&args=NDU+NDc)
[`++**--/`](http://silos.tryitonline.net/#code=OnMKZGVmIDogbGJsIEcgR09UTwpyZWFkSU8KaS00NgppZiBpIGEKaSsyCmlmIGkgYgppKzIKaWYgaSBjCmkrMQppZiBpIGQKRyBlCjphCkcgdgo6cAphLTEKYS8yCkcgbwo6dgphKzEKaWYgYSBwCmEtMQpqPWEKai8yCms9agprKjIKay1hCmEvMgppZiBrIHQKRyBvCmxibHQKYS0xCjpvCkcgcwo6YgphLTEKRyBzCjpjCmErMQpHIHMKOmQKYSoyCkcgcwo6ZQpwcmludEludCBh&input=&args=NDM+NDM+NDI+NDI+NDU+NDU+NDc)
[`*///*-*+-+`](http://silos.tryitonline.net/#code=OnMKZGVmIDogbGJsIEcgR09UTwpyZWFkSU8KaS00NgppZiBpIGQKaSsyCmlmIGkgYwppKzIKaWYgaSB0CmkrMQppZiBpIG0KRyBlCjpkCmEvMgpHIHMKOmMKYS0xCkcgcwo6dAphKzEKRyBzCjptCmEqMgpHIHMKOmUKcHJpbnRJbnQgYQ&input=&args=NDI+NDc+NDc+NDc+NDI+NDU+NDI+NDM+NDU+NDM)

Comment: is loadLine golfier?

Comment: The OP clarified; `-/` should return **-1**, not **0**.

Comment: @Dennis fixed. Added a lot of bytes though :/

Answer (score 10):

## Turing Machine - 23 states (684 bytes)

Try it here - [permalink](http://morphett.info/turing/turing.html?a7f0ec58ccc0040e49b75282d8caf030)

```
0 * * r 0
0 _ . l 1
1 * * l 1
1 _ * l 2
2 * 0 r 3
3 _ * r 3
3 + _ l +
3 - _ l -
3 x _ l x
3 / _ l /
+ _ * l +
+ * * * 4
4 - * l 5
4 _ 1 r 6
4 0 1 l 7
4 1 0 l 4
- _ * l -
- * * * 5
5 - * l 4
5 _ * r 8
5 0 1 l 5
5 1 0 l 7
x * * l x
x 1 0 l 9
x 0 0 l a
9 _ 1 r 6
9 1 1 l 9
9 0 1 l a
a _ _ r 6
a 1 0 l 9
a 0 0 l a
/ _ * l /
/ * * l b
b * * l b
b _ * r c
c 0 0 r d
c 1 0 r e
d * * l 7 
d 0 0 r d
d 1 0 r e
e _ * l 7
e - * l 4
e 0 1 r d
e 1 1 r e
8 * * r 8
8 - _ r 3
8 _ - r 3
7 * * l 7
7 _ * r f
f 0 _ r f
f 1 * r 6
f * _ l g
g * 0 r 6
6 * * r 6
6 _ * r 3
3 . _ l h
h _ * l h
h - _ l i
h * * l halt
i * * l i
i _ - r halt
```

Input should not contain any '*' since it is a special character in Turing machine code. Use 'x' instead.
Outputs the answer in binary.

**Unobfuscated Code**

```
init2 * * r init2
init2 _ . l init0
init0 * * l init0
init0 _ * l init1
init1 * 0 r readop
readop _ * r readop
readop + _ l +
readop - _ l -
readop x _ l x
readop / _ l /
+ _ * l +
+ * * * inc
inc - * l dec
inc _ 1 r return
inc 0 1 l zero
inc 1 0 l inc
- _ * l -
- * * * dec
dec - * l inc
dec _ * r neg
dec 0 1 l dec
dec 1 0 l zero
x * * l x
x 1 0 l x1
x 0 0 l x0
x1 _ 1 r return
x1 1 1 l x1
x1 0 1 l x0
x0 _ _ r return
x0 1 0 l x1
x0 0 0 l x0
/ _ * l /
/ * * l //
// * * l //
// _ * r div
div 0 0 r div0
div 1 0 r div1
div0 * * l zero 
div0 0 0 r div0
div0 1 0 r div1
div1 _ * l zero
div1 - * l inc
div1 0 1 r div0
div1 1 1 r div1
neg * * r neg
neg - _ r readop
neg _ - r readop
zero * * l zero
zero _ * r zero1
zero1 0 _ r zero1
zero1 1 * r return
zero1 * _ l zero2
zero2 * 0 r return
return * * r return
return _ * r readop
readop . _ l fin
fin _ * l fin
fin - _ l min
fin * * l halt
min * * l min
min _ - r halt
```

**Explanation of the states:**

*Initialization:*
*These states are visited once at the beginning of each run, starting with init2*

- init2: Move all the way to the right and put a '.'. That way the TM knows when to stop. Change to 'init0'.
- init0: Move all the back to the left until the head reads a space. Then move one cell to the left. Change to 'init1'.
- init1: Put a zero and move one cell to the right and change to 'readop'.

*Reading instructions:*
*These states will be visited multiple times throughout the program*

- readop: Moves all the way to the right until it reads an operator or the '.'. If it hits an operator, change to the corresponding state (+,-,x,/). If it hits a '.', change to state 'fin'.
- return: Returns the head to the empty space between the running total and the operators. Then changes to 'readop'.

*Operations:*
*These operations do the actual dirty work*

- +: Move to the left until the head reads any non-
  whitespace character. If this character is a '-', move left and change to 'dec'. Otherwise, change to 'inc'.
- -: Similar to '+', except change to 'inc' if there is a '-' and 'dec' otherwise.
- inc: If the digit under the head is a 0 (or a whitespace), change it to 1 and change to 'zero'. If the digit is a 1, change it to 0, then repeat on the next digit.
- dec: Similar to inc, except 1 goes to 0, 0 goes to 1, and if the head reads a whitespace, change to 'neg'.
- x, x0, x1: Bitshift the number one to the left. Change to 'return'.
- /, //, div, div0, div1: Move all the way to the right of the number, then bitshift one to the right. If there is a '-', change to 'inc'. This simulates rounding down negative numbers. Otherwise, change to 'zero'
- neg: Place a '-' after the number then change to 'readop'
- zero, zero1, zero2: Remove leading zeros and change to 'readop'

*Cleanup:*
*Makes the output presentable*

- fin, min: Move the '-' in front of the number if necessary. Halt.

Comment: Thought reading this code was very very cool. So thanks for brightening up my day.

Answer (score 8):

## [Perl 6](http://perl6.org),  <s>53</s>  52  bytes

```perl6
{([Ro] %(<+ - * />Z=>*+1,*-1,* *2,*div 2){.comb})(0)}
```

```perl6
{[Ro](%(<+ - * />Z=>*+1,*-1,*×2,*div 2){.comb})(0)}
```

### Explanation:

```perl6
# bare block lambda that has one implicit parameter ｢$_｣
{
  (
    # reduce the code refs using ring operator ｢∘｣ in reverse ｢R｣
    [R[o]]

      # produce a hash from:
      %(

        # list of pairs of "operator" to code ref
        # ( similar to ｢'+' => { $^a + 1 }｣ )

          # keys
          < + - * / >

        # keys and values joined using infix zip operator ｢Z｣
        # combined with the infix Pair constructor operator ｢=>｣
        Z[=>]

          # values (Whatever lambdas)
          * + 1,
          * - 1,
          * × 2, # same as ｢* * 2｣
          * div 2,

      ){

        # split the block's argument into chars
        # and use them as keys to the hash
        # which will result in a list of code refs
        .comb

      }

  # call composed code ref with 0
  )(0)
}
```

### Usage:

```perl6
my $input = '++**--/'
my $output = {[Ro](%(<+ - * />Z=>*+1,*-1,*×2,*div 2){.comb})(0)}.( $input );
say $output; # 3
say $output.^name; # Int
```

Answer (score 8):

## C, <s>63</s> <s>62</s> 57 bytes

```c
s,t;c(char*x){for(;*x;s+=t<4?t?2-t:s:-s>>1)t=*x++%6;s=s;}
```

[Wandbox](http://melpon.org/wandbox/permlink/w5TOvhR7SKgy2akp)

Answer (score 6):

## [05AB1E](http://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E), 20 bytes

*Thanks to **Emigna** for fixing the `-/`-bug!*

For 16 bytes if it wasn't integer division: `Î"+-*/""><·;"‡.V`.

```
Î…+-*"><·"‡'/"2÷":.V
```

Explanation:

```
Î                      # Push 0, which is our starting variable, and input
 …+-*                  # Push the string "+-*"
     "><·"             # Push the string "><·"
          ‡            # Transliterate. The following changes:
                           "+" -> ">"
                           "-" -> "<"
                           "*" -> "·"
           '/"2÷":     # Replace "/" by "2÷"
                  .V   # Evaluate the code as 05AB1E code...
                           '>' is increment by 1
                           '<' is decrement by 1
                           '·' is multiply by 2
                           '2÷' is integer divide by two
                       # Implicitly output the result
```

Uses the **CP-1252** encoding. [Try it online!](http://05ab1e.tryitonline.net/#code=w47igKYrLSoiPjzCtyLigKEnLyIyw7ciOi5W&input=LS8)

Comment: The OP clarified; `-/` should return **-1**, not **0**.

Comment: The negative number division issue could be fixed with `Î…+-*"><·"‡'/"2÷":.V` for the same byte count.

Comment: @Dennis Fixed the problem.

Answer (score 5):

## JavaScript ES6, <s>80</s> 68 bytes

```
k=>[...k].reduce((c,o)=>+{"+":c+1,"-":c-1,"*":c*2,"/":c/2|0}‌​[o],0)
```

Saved a whopping 12 bytes thanks to Neil!

Comment: Second answer would be more readable if you removed the `"c"+` and wrote `"c+1 c-1 c*2 c/2|0".split` etc.

Comment: For the first answer, why not write `o=>c=[c+1,c-1,c*2,c/2|0]["+-*/".indexOf(o)]`, or I think you can then go on to save a further byte using `o=>c={"+":c+1,"-":c-1,"*":c*2,"/":c/2|0}[o]`.

Comment: `k=>[...k].reduce((c,o)=>+{"+":c+1,"-":c-1,"*":c*2,"/":c/2|0}[o],0)` might work out even shorter still, but I've lost count...

Comment: @Neil Ah, yes, I forgot about this

Comment: @Neil fantastic!

Comment: @DanTheMan Did you actually read the answer? `n/2|0` performs integer division.

Comment: @ConorO'Brien I was confusing `|`  and `||`. Sorry! Try to not be so condescending next time though.

Comment: You somehow got to zero-width characters between `}` and `[o]`, so this is actually only 66 bytes long. Also, the OP clarified; `-/` should return **-1**, not **0**.

Comment: @Dennis Excellent, that saves another byte by using `>>1` instead of `/2|0`.

Comment: @Dennis I will fix the next opportunity I can.

Comment: @LeakyNun done.

Answer (score 5):

## Ruby, <s>48</s> <s>44</s> 42 + 1 = 43 bytes

+1 byte for `-n` flag. Takes input on STDIN.

```ruby
i=0
gsub(/./){i=i.send$&,"+-"[$&]?1:2}
p i
```

See it on ideone (uses `$_` since ideone doesn't take command line flags): http://ideone.com/3udQ3H

Answer (score 5):

## PHP 76 Bytes

```
for(;$c=$argv[1][$n++];)eval('$s=floor($s'.$c.(2-ord($c)%11%3).');');echo$s;
```

Answer (score 4):

## Mathematica, <s>83</s> <s>73</s> 70 bytes

<sup>*10 bytes saved due to [@MartinEnder](http://ppcg.lol/users/8478).*</sup>

```
(#/*##2&@@#/.Thread[{"+","-","*","/"}->{#+1&,#-1&,2#&,⌊#/2⌋&}])@0&
```

Anonymous function. Takes a list of characters as input and returns a number as output. Golfing suggestions welcome.

Answer (score 4):

## Python 2, <s>58</s> 56 bytes

-2 bytes thanks to @Lynn

```python
r=0
for c in input():exec'r=r'+c+`2-ord(c)%11%3`
print r
```

The ordinals of the characters `+-*/` are `43,45,42,47` modulo 11 these are `10,1,9,3` modulo 3 those are `1,1,0,0`, 2 less those are `1,1,2,2` giving the amounts we need for each operation: `r=r+1`, `r=r-1`, `r=r*2`, and `r=r/2`

---

Previous:

```python
r=0
for c in input():exec'r=r'+c+`(ord(c)%5==2)+1`
print r
```

Comment: How about `2-ord(c)%11%3`?

Comment: @Lynn Well I'll take it if its OK with you? (but really think it's enough of a change you could post it)

Comment: Go ahead :) ----

Answer (score 4):

## [S.I.L.O.S](http://github.com/rjhunjhunwala/S.I.L.O.S), <s>175</s> 164 bytes

```
loadLine
a=256
o=get a
lbla
a+1
o-42
p=o
p-1
p/p
p-1
r-p
s=o
s-3
s/s
s-1
r+s
m=o
m/m
m-2
m|
r*m
t=r
t%2
d=o
d-5
d/d
d-1
t*d
d-1
d|
r-t
r/d
o=get a
if o a
printInt r
```

[Try it online!](http://silos.tryitonline.net/#code=bG9hZExpbmUKYT0yNTYKbz1nZXQgYQpsYmxhCmErMQpvLTQyCnA9bwpwLTEKcC9wCnAtMQpyLXAKcz1vCnMtMwpzL3MKcy0xCnIrcwptPW8KbS9tCm0tMgptfApyKm0KdD1yCnQlMgpkPW8KZC01CmQvZApkLTEKdCpkCmQtMQpkfApyLXQKci9kCm89Z2V0IGEKaWYgbyBhCnByaW50SW50IHI&input=&args=KysqKi0tLw)

Sane input method. Correct integer division (round towards -infinity).

Answer (score 4):

### Javascript (ES6), 57 bytes (array) / 60 bytes (integer)

Returning an array of all intermediate results:

```
o=>[...o].map(c=>x=[x>>1,x+1,x*2,x-1][eval(2+c+3)&3],x=0)
```

For instance, the output for `"++**--/"` will be `[1, 2, 4, 8, 7, 6, 3]`.

Returning only the final result:

```
o=>[...o].reduce((x,c)=>[x>>1,x+1,x*2,x-1][eval(2+c+3)&3],0)
```

#### How it works

Both solutions are based on the same idea: using the perfect hash function `eval(2+c+3)&3` to map the different operator characters `c` in `[0, 3]`.

```
 operator | eval(2+c+3)  | eval(2+c+3)&3
----------+--------------+---------------
    +     |  2+3 = 5     |    5 & 3 = 1
    -     |  2-3 = -1    |   -1 & 3 = 3
    *     |  2*3 = 6     |    6 & 3 = 2
    /     |  2/3 ~= 0.67 | 0.67 & 3 = 0
```

Answer (score 4):

## C#, <s>87</s> 81 bytes

```
int f(string s){int i=0;foreach(var c in s)i=c<43?i*2:c<46?i+44-c:i>>1;return i;}
```

Ungolfed:

```
int f(string s)
{
    int i = 0;

    foreach (var c in s)
        i = c < 43 ? i * 2
          : c < 46 ? i + 44 - c
          : i >> 1;

    return i;
}
```

Input is assumed to be valid. Division by two is done by shifting right one bit, because regular division always rounds towards zero, and bit shifting always rounds down. Increment and decrement make handy use of the 1 distance between the ASCII codes for `+` and `-`.

Comment: Some love for new C#6 syntax and aggregate method of Linq? `int f(string s)=>s.Aggregate(0,(i,c)=>c<43?i*2:c<46?i+44-c:i>>1);` (65 bytes)

Comment: @CyrilGandon as far as I'm aware that would have to include the "using System.Linq;", making it 19 longer and putting it at 84 bytes. Which is why I didn't do it.

Answer (score 3):

## JavaScript (ES6), 57

```js
a=>[...a].map(c=>a=c<'+'?a<<1:c<'-'?-~a:c<'/'?~-a:a>>1)|a
```

Note: the initial value for accumulator is the program string, using bit operations (~, >>, <<, |) it is converted to 0 at first use.

As a side note, the clever answer of @xnor would score 40 ported to javascript:

```js
a=>[...a].map(c=>a=eval(~~a+c+2))&&a>>1
```

(if you like this, vote for him)

**Test**

```js
f=a=>[...a].map(c=>a=c<'+'?a<<1:c<'-'?-~a:c<'/'?~-a:a>>1)|a

function update() {
  O.textContent = f(I.value);
}

update()
```

```html
<input value='++**--/' id=I oninput='update()'><pre id=O></pre>
```

Answer (score 3):

### GNU sed, <s>65</s> <s>59</s> 57 bytes

**Edit:** 2 bytes shorter thanks to [Toby Speight](/users/39490)'s comments

```
s/[+-]/1&/g
s/*/2&/g
s:/:d0>@2&:g
s/.*/dc -e"0[1-]s@&p"/e
```

**Run:**

```sh
sed -f simple_calculator.sed <<< "*///*-*+-+"
```

**Output:**

```sh
-1
```

The `sed` script prepares the input for the `dc` shell call at the end, the latter accepting the input in [Reverse Polish notation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reverse_Polish_notation). On division, if the number is negative (`d0>`), the `[1-]` decrement command stored in register `@` is called. Conversion example: `+ - * /` --> `1+ 1- 2* d0>@2/`.

Comment: You don't need the quotes around the argument to dc, if there's no spaces, and no files matching the `[1-]` pattern...

Comment: @TobySpeight In my mind I switched the meaning of `s` with `S`. I forgot that it doesn't replace the registry's stack, it pushes onto it, having the contrary effect of what I wanted (since I used it for every `/`). The quotes are still needed because you have `/` symbols in it making the string interpreted as a file path :) I shaved 1 byte more by removing the space after the `-e`.

Comment: dc won't intepret argument of `-e` as a filename, so you don't need quotes for the `/` - try it!  I think it's a reasonable for a code-golf to require that the current working directory not contain any files beginning with `01s@` or `0-s@`.

Comment: @TobySpeight you were right about `-e` regarding `/`, however the quotes are still required as I just saw now. The `>` is interpreted directly by the shell as a redirect operator I think, since I got this error: `cannot create @2/d0: Directory nonexistent`

Comment: Ah, yes, I didn't consider the `>`.  You do need quotes, after all.  Apologies for (attempting to) mislead!  And, although adding a backslash looks like one character, it needs to be doubled in a `s///` replacement, so no benefit there...

Answer (score 3):

## PHP, 75 bytes

This uses a modified version of [Jörg Hülsermann's](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/59107/j%C3%B6rg-h%C3%BClsermann) answer.

```
eval(preg_replace('~.~','$s=($s\0(2-ord("\0")%11%3))|0;',$argv[1]));echo$s;
```

It heavily relies on string substitution, using a simple regular expression (`~.~`).

The variable `$s` is re-assigned with the new value for each character. At the end, it outputs the result.

---

**Note**: This is meant to be executed using the `-r` flag.

---

Try it here:

```js
if('\0' == "\0")
{
 $argv = Array($s = 0, prompt());
 function preg_replace($pattern, $replacement, $subject)
 {
  $regexp = new RegExp($pattern.replace(new RegExp('~', 'g'), ''), 'g');
  return $subject.replace($regexp, $replacement.split('\0').join('$&'));
 }
 
 function printf($string)
 {
  console.log($string);
 }
 
 function ord($chr)
 {
  return $chr.charCodeAt(0);
 }
}
else
{
    if(!isset($argv))
    {
        $argv = array('', '++*+');
    }
}

eval(preg_replace('~.~','$s=($s\0(2-ord("\0")%11%3))|0;',$argv[1]));printf($s);
```

Or try on: http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/7d2adc2a500268c011222d8d953d9b837f2312aa

Differences:

- Instead of `echo$s`, I'm using `sprintf($s)`.
  Both perform the same action on numbers. Since this is just for testing, it is fine.
- In case there's no passed argument, it will run as if you passed `++*+` as the first argument, which should show `5`.

Comment: Yay! The `e` modifier is back! :D

Comment: @Titus I don't get it. Can you elaborate a little?

Comment: PHP before version 7 had a [pattern modifier `e`](http://php.net/manual/de/reference.pcre.pattern.modifiers.php), which was replaced by [`preg_replace_callback`](http://php.net/preg_replace_callback) and could be abused to ... but this isn´t quite that.

Comment: @Titus That patern modifier was used to tell that the output would be actual PHP code, and to try to keep the syntax correct. This here, doesn't use it, but replace every single character with a piece of code to execute, regardless of it's syntax. Bad inputs will cause severe security issues.

Comment: I know. But it resembles.

Comment: @Titus To be honest, it does resemble. This answer would (probably) benefict from it. But, to be even more honest, I'm more proud of the polyglot I wrote to test the basic implementation in PHP and Javascript (in a StackSnippet)

Answer (score 3):

## Java, 77 bytes

```
int f(String s){return s.chars().reduce(0,(r,c)->c<43?r*2:c<46?r+44-c:r>>1);}
```

Uses java 8 streams.

Comment: Nice answer, and welcome to the site! I don't know anything about java, but can you change `r >> 1` to `r>>1` and save 2 bytes?

Comment: You're absolutely correct, thanks @DJMcMayhem

Comment: Awesome, glad I could help! One more note, I'm counting 77 bytes. Did you happen to include the newline in your byte count? You can take one more byte off since that isn't necessary.

Comment: Correct again @DJMcMayhem , aparently wc counts the null-terminanting byte or something...

Comment: as you are using java8, why don't define function by using lambda, `s->s.chars().reduce(0,(r,c)->c<43?r*2:c<46?r+44-c:r>>1);` that will give you 56 bytes

Answer (score 2):

## Python 3, <s>98</s> <s>66</s> 60 bytes

Thanks Tukkax!

Not as golfy as the other answer, but I can't compete with them without plagiarism.

```
i=0
for c in input():i+=[1,-i//2,-1,i][ord(c)%23%4]
print(i)
```

Also, I have a recursive lambda solution as well

**<s>73</s> 67 bytes** (improved!)

```
s=lambda x,z=0:s(x[1:],z+[1,-z//2,-1,z][ord(x[0])%23%4])if x else z
```

Comment: By applying part of your recursive solution to the procedural version: 60 bytes: `i=0
for c in input():i+=[1,-i//2,-1,i][ord(c)%23%4]
print(i)`. (not formatted properly of course). Also I think you should mention that you're using Python3. In Python2, `input()` would evaluate to `int(raw_input())`.

Comment: @TuukkaX doesn't work for z=0 (`+-` does 1)

Comment: oh yes, my mistake.

Comment: Add the title Python3 please.

Answer (score 2):

### Pyke, <s>24</s> 22 bytes

```
\*\}:\/\e:\+\h:\-\t:0E
```

[Try it here!](http://pyke.catbus.co.uk/?code=%5C%2a%5C%7D%3A%5C%2F%5Ce%3A%5C%2B%5Ch%3A%5C-%5Ct%3A0E&input=%2B%2B%2a%2a--%2F)

#### Or 12 bytes (noncompetitive)

```
~:"ht}e".:0E
```

[Try it here!](http://pyke.catbus.co.uk/?code=%7E%3A%22ht%7De%22.%3A0E&input=%2B%2B%2a%2a--%2F)

Add `translate` node - basically multiple find and replace.

```
~:           -   "+-*/"
        .:   -  input.translate(^, V)
  "ht}e"     -   "ht}e"
          0E - eval(^, stack=0)
```

Answer (score 2):

### Batch, 61 bytes

```
@set n=
@for %%a in (%*)do @set/an=n%%a2^&-2
@cmd/cset/an/2
```

Translation of @xnor's xcellent Python answer.

Answer (score 2):

## PHP, <s>104</s> <s>102</s> 82 bytes

First version with eval:

```
$i=0;while($c<9999)eval('$i'.['+'=>'++','-'=>'--','*'=>'*=2','/'=>'>>=1'][$argv[1]{$c++}].';');echo$i;
```

Second version with ternary operators:

```
while($o=ord($argv[1]{$c++}))$i=$o<43?$i*2:($o<44?$i+1:($o<46?$i-1:$i>>1));echo$i;
```

Takes the input string as first argument from the command line.

<s>This "only" works for input strings shorter than 10,000 characters - which should be plenty. Tested with all the test cases, unfortunately can't save on the initialization in the beginning.</s> Second version works with strings of any length and without initialization. :-)

The main element is the eval function which manipulates `$i` based on a map of arithmetic operations, which are pretty straightforward except for the division. PHP returns a float when using `/` and `intdiv` is too many bytes, so we do [a right-shift](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.bitwise.php).

### Updates

1. Saved 2 bytes by shortening `$i=$i>>1` to `$i>>=1` for integer division.
2. Threw out eval in favor of ternary operators.

Answer (score 2):

## R, 201 bytes

**Golfed**

```
p=.Primitive;"-"="+"=function(x)p("+")(x,1);body(`-`)[[1]]=p("-");"*"="/"=function(x)p("*")(x,2);body(`/`)[[1]]=p("%/%");Reduce(function(f, ...)f(...),rev(mget(strsplit(scan(stdin(),""),"")[[1]])),0,T)
```

**Commented**

```
p = .Primitive                       # Redefine
"-" = "+" = function(x)p("+")(x,1)   # Define - and +
body(`-`)[[1]] = p("-")              # Change the body, what we do to save a byte
"*" = "/" = function(x)p("*")(x,2)   # Same as above
body(`/`)[[1]] = p("%/%")            # Same as above
Reduce(function(f, ...)f(...),       # Function wrapper to evaluate list of func.  
  rev(mget(strsplit(scan(stdin(),""),"")[[1]])), # Strsplit input into list of functions
  init = 0,                                      # Starting Arg = 1
  right = T)                                     # Right to left = True
```

Strategy is to refine the `+, -, %` operators. Split the string then parse the string into a long list of functions, to be fed into `Reduce()'s` accumulator.

Couldn't golf it anymore. If someone can get `b=body<-` to work, there could be a few bytes of savings (refine every function with `b` after `"-"="+"="/"="*"`). Initially tried to substitute and parse eval, but the order of operations and parentheses were terrifying.

Comment: This is a year later, but I managed to get it down 10 bytes by swapping your approach a bit -- you can drop 8 bytes by removing the space between `f, ...` in the definition of the `Reduce` function and getting rid of `stdin()` in `scan` but I just tried a naive approach that dropped two more bytes by defining the functions a little differently.
https://tio.run/##XcvLCsMgEAXQrwnO6Gge29B/KKW7EDBYU4TmgZqQv7dmU2gWcxfn3vEp6UIU@jZus4lumeHAQ9StLuQF5Yn8grzJWP6juns3ueh2Cyx3DOGgBtuHfW3Gwm84klIKRziTvN1hetsI6xCirfIjoxB9WD8uQjDDDMQYntd1dd9T7hGRKnpiEoJzKcv0BQ

Answer (score 1):

## Python3, <strike>98 85</strike> 74 bytes

```
C=lambda s,n:s and C(s[1:],{3:n+1,5:n-1,2:n*2,7:n/2}[ord(s[0])%10])or n//1
```

A recursive solution that loops over the string and takes the (modulo 10) from the ASCII value of the iterated character and treats the carried number accordingly. The dictionary keys are the last digits of the possible ASCII values that may occur (+, -, *, /) and the values are the corresponding results for the symbol.We pass the input string `s` forward by taking everything onward from the next character with `s[1:]` (thanks to [@Destructible Watermelon!](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/55896/destructible-watermelon)).

Could be shortened even more, by picking the actions from a list and moduloing to keep the index in range, but that feels like plagiarism at this point, so unless I find my own method for that, it won't happen.

Called like: `C("+-+**+/",0)` ==> 2.0

(Ps. Is it allowed to return `-1.0` from input `-/`?)

Answer (score 1):

### PHP, 79 bytes

```
<?$i=0;switch($_POST['a']){case"+":$i+1;case"-":$i-1;case"/":$i/2;case"*":$i*2}
```

Comment: Include the bytecount in your header, remove uneccesary spaces and use 1-letter variable names.

Comment: Is this even golfed?! :-D

Comment: @TùxCräftîñg I did it.

Comment: You divide and multiply by `1`; you need to divide and multiply by `2`

Comment: @TùxCräftîñg I did it.

Comment: Please update your bytecount... The bytecount here is of 81 bytes

Comment: I typed "81", What did you see

Comment: If I POST "-+", I get `0`, in `$i`, and `$i` is never outputted.

Comment: Shouldn´t there be a loop of some kind? Save one byte with `$_GET` instead of `$_POST`.

Answer (score 1):

## Lex + C, <s>78</s>, <s>74</s>, 73 bytes

The first character is a space.

```
 c;F(){yylex(c=0);return c;}
%%
\+ c++;
- c--;
\* c*=2;
\/ c=floor(c/2.);
```

Reads from `stdin`, returns result.

Compile with `lex golfed.l && cc lex.yy.c main.c -lm -lfl`, test main:

```
int main() { printf("%d\n", F()); }
```

Answer (score 1):

## PHP, <strike>146</strike> <strike>138</strike>, <strike>133</strike>, 131 bytes

```
$a=$_POST['s'];$i=0;while($a){$c=substr($a,0,1);$i=$c=='+'?$i+=1:($c=='-'?$i-1:($c=='*'?$i*2:round($i/2)));$a=substr($a,1);}echo$i;
```

1. Takes argument from $_POST['s'].
2. Uses ternary operator as "if's".
3. Takes one character at a time, parse that char in operation, then continue reading next char
4. EDIT 1: Shortened "*while(strlen($a))*" to "*while($a)*"
5. EDIT 2: Removed some useless paranthesis
6. EDIT 3. Removed extra space after last "*echo*"

Comment: I think with even PHP 5.5 having reached EOL it's safe to say that nobody SHOULD use PHP 4 anymore, so the "5+" is not necessary, imho.

Comment: That is ok. For some scripts, it is important to show PHP version, maybe here it's not the case. Thanks, however.

Comment: Yes, but if they start including the [leaderboard snippet](http://meta.codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/5139/leaderboard-snippet) then your entry will be the top entry for the language "PHP 5+" while another one's entry will be leading "PHP 5.6" and maybe somebody else with worse score posts for "PHP 5.6.13 and up" ... You see my point? :-)

Comment: That is correct. Thanks, again

Comment: You can change `$_POST['s']` to `$_GET[s]`, which is bad practice but saves you 2 bytes.You might also try to remove the bracketrs of the while (-2) if you add a newline before the echo (+1) Not 100% sure about that.

Comment: I had tried with $_GET, but because of "/" chars in string there is a problem with resulted link. Regarding paranthesis for while, that is ok.

Comment: Tried it. It is not ok while without brackets.

Answer (score 1):

## Javascript (ES5), 127 bytes

```
function(b){for(a=c=0;a<b.length;++a)switch(b[a]){case"+":++c;break;case"-":--c;break;case"*":c*=2;break;case"/":c/=2}return c}
```

Ungolfed:

```
function c(a){
  c=0;
  for(var i=0;i<a.length;++i){
    switch(a[i]){
      case "+":++c;break;
      case "-":--c;break;
      case "*":c*=2;break;
      case "/":c/=2;break;
    }
  }
  return c;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

## Pyth, 23 bytes

```
FNQ=Z.v%".&%sZ2_2"N;/Z2
```

A full program that takes input as a string and prints the result.

This is a port of @xnor's [Python answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/91509/55526).

[Try it online](https://pyth.herokuapp.com/?code=FNQ%3DZ.v%25%22.%26%25sZ2_2%22N%3B%2FZ2&debug=0)

**How it works**

```
FNQ=Z.v%".&%sZ2_2"N;/Z2   Program. Input: Q. Z initialised as 0
FNQ                       For. For N in Q:
        ".&%sZ2_2"         String. Literal string ".&%sZ2_2"
       %          N        String format. Replace %s with the current operator N
           %sZ2            Operator. Yield Z*2, Z//2, Z+2, Z-2 as appropriate
         .&    _2          Bitwise and. Result of above & -2
     .v                    Evaluate. Yield the result of the expression
   =Z                      Assignment. Assign result of above to Z
                   ;      End. End for loop
                    /Z2   Integer division. Yield Z//2
                          Print. Print the above implicitly
```

Comment: Converting Python to Pyth is mostly a bad idea. `u@[yGhG0tG0/G2)CHQ0` 19 bytes

Comment: @Jakube Thanks - I am very new to Pyth, so any advice is appreciated. Feel free to post that as a separate answer, since it is a different approach.

Answer (score 1):

## Ruby, 37 bytes

```
#!ruby -n
gsub(/./){eval"$.=$./2*2#$&2"}
p$./2
```

The shebang counts as 1 byte. This program uses [xnor's creative approach](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/91509/45268). We avoid the need to initialise an accumulator variable by using `$.`. As it has a value of 1 after the input is read, we have to clear the LSB before applying each operator. This also requires changing `&-2` to `/2*2` for the correct precedence.

Answer (score 1):

## Java 7, 73 bytes

```
int c(char[]i){int r=0;for(int c:i)r=c<43?r*2:c<46?r+44-c:r>>1;return r;}
```

Shamelessly stolen from [*@Scepheo*'s amazing C# answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/91537/52210) and implemented in Java 7.

**Ungolfed & test cases:**

[Try it here.](https://ideone.com/xgWtDG)

```
class M{
  static int c(char[] i){
    int r = 0;
    for(int c : i) {
      r = c < 43
           ? r * 2
           : c < 46
              ? r+44 - c
              : r >> 1;
    }
    return r;
  }

  public static void main(String[] a){
    System.out.println(c("*///*-*+-+".toCharArray()));
    System.out.println(c("/*+/*+++/*///*/+-+//*+-+-/----*-*-+++*+**+/*--///+*-/+//*//-+++--++/-**--/+--/*-/+*//*+-*-*/*+*+/+*-".toCharArray()));
    System.out.println(c("+++-+--/-*/---++/-+*-//+/++-*--+*+/*/*/++--++-+//++--*/***-*+++--+-*//-*/+*/+-*++**+--*/*//-*--**-/-*+**-/*-**/*+*-*/--+/+/+//-+*/---///+**////-*//+-+-/+--/**///*+//+++/+*++**++//**+**+-*/+/*/*++-/+**+--+*++++/-*-/*+--/++*/-++/-**++++/-/+/--*/-/+---**//*///-//*+-*----+//--/-/+*/-+++-+*-*+*+-/-//*-//+/*-+//+/+/*-/-/+//+**/-****/-**-//+/+-+/*-+*++*/-/++*/-//*--+*--/-+-+/+/**/-***+/-/++-++*+*-+*+*-+-//+/-++*+/*//*-+/+*/-+/-/*/-/-+*+**/*//*+/+---+*+++*+/+-**/-+-/+*---/-*+/-++*//*/-+-*+--**/-////*/--/*--//-**/*++*+/*+/-+/--**/*-+*+/+-*+*+--*///+-++/+//+*/-+/**--//*/+++/*+*////+-*-//--*+/*/-+**/*//+*+-//+--+*-+/-**-*/+//*+---*+//*/+**/*--/--+/*-*+*++--*+//+*+-++--+-*-*-+--**+/+*-/+*+-/---+-*+-+-/++/+*///*/*-+-*//-+-++/++/*/-++/**--+-////-//+/*//+**/*+-+/+/+///*+*///*-/+/*/-//-*-**//-/-+--+/-*--+-++**++//*--/*++--*-/-///-+/+//--+*//-**-/*-*/+*/-*-*//--++*//-*/++//+/-++-+-*/*-+++**-/-*++++**+-+++-+-***-+//+-/**-+/*+****-*+++*/-*-/***/-/*+/*****++*+/-/-**-+-*-*-++**/*+-/*-+*++-/+/-++*-/*-****-*".toCharArray()));
  }
}
```

**Output:**

```
-1
-17
18773342
```

Answer (score 1):

## ARM Machine Code, 30 bytes

Hex Dump (little endian):

```
2000 f811 2b01 b14a 2a2a bf08 0040 d0f8 2a2e bf3a 3a2c 1a80 1040 e7f2 4770
```

This is a function that takes in a string, and returns the accumulated result. In C, the function would be declared int sioc(int dummy, char* string) where the dummy argument is ignored. Tested on the Raspberry Pi 3. No libraries or system calls are used.

Ungolfed assembly:

```
.syntax unified
.text
.global sioc
.thumb_func
sioc:
    @Input: r0 - dummy argument
    @r1 - string of operations
    @Output: r0 - result of those operations
    movs r0,#0 @Initialize accumulator to 0
    loop:
        ldrb r2,[r1],#1 @r2=*r1++
        cbz r2,end @If (r2==0), goto end
    mul:
        cmp r2,#42
        it eq @if r2==42
        lsleq r0,r0,#1 @r0<<=1
        beq loop @continue
    addsub: @else
        cmp r2,#46
        itte lo @If r2<46, then r2 is either + or -
        sublo r2,r2,#44
        sublo r0,r0,r2 @Add 1 if r2 is +, subtract 1 if r0 is -
        asrhs r0,r0,#1 @else arithmatically shift right by 1
        b loop @while (true)
    end:
        bx lr
```

Testing script (also assembly):

```
.syntax unified
.text
.global main
.thumb_func
main:
    ldr r1,[r1,#4] @r0=argv[1]
    bl sioc
    mov r1,r0
    adr r0,msg
    bl printf
    movs r7,#1
    swi #0
.balign 4
msg:
    .asciz "%d\n"
```

Answer (score 1):

## Java 8, 56 bytes

```
s->s.chars().reduce(0,(r,c)->c<43?r*2:c<46?r+44-c:r>>1);
```

Answer (score 1):

## Haskell - 70 bytes

```
f x=foldl1(flip(.))[[(*2),succ,id,pred,id,(`div`2)]!!(ord n-42)|n<-x]0
```

64 if I may take the input in RPN:

```
f x=foldl1(.)[[(*2),succ,id,pred,id,(`div`2)]!!(ord n-42)|n<-x]0
```

In addition to `+` `-` `*` `/` my implementation also support `,` and `.`, both of which does nothing. It crashes for any other input.

Answer (score 1):

### Racket 116 bytes

```
(λ(s)(let((l(string->list s))(a 0))(for((i l))(set! a(match i[#\+(+ a 1)][#\-(- a 1)][#\*(* a 2)][#\/(/ a 2)])))a))
```

Ungolfed version:

```
(define f
  (lambda(s)
    (let ((l (string->list s))
          (a 0))
      (for ((i l))
        (set! a (match i
                  [#\+ (+ a 1)]
                  [#\- (- a 1)]
                  [#\* (* a 2)]
                  [#\/ (/ a 2)]
                )))
      a)))
```

Testing:

```
(f "++**--/")

3
```

Answer (score 1):

## [GolfScript](https://tio.run/##S8/PSStOLsosKPn/v9pQu9ZKSVvJutpQF8jQBTKM9IEMfRBDC8jQUrI2iDHUr06oq9X//19LX19fS1dLW1cbAA) - 45 bytes

```
{1+}:"+";{1-}:"-";{2/}:"/";{2*}:"*";0\1/{`~}/
```

#### Explanation

```
{1+}:"+";  # Creates aliases for operators
{1-}:"-";
{2/}:"/";
{2*}:"*";
0\1/       # Pushes 0 and splits the string in bytes
{`~}/      # Executes each character
```

Comment: you can shave off 2 bytes by using ) and ( instead of 1+ and 1- 

and you can also lose 2 more by using ]; after declaring the aliases instead of removing them from the stack one at a time

Answer (score 0):

## TSQL, 115 bytes

After some golfing I was finally able to replace `-IIF(@<0,@,@+1)/2` with `(@+ABS(@%2))/-2` saving 2 bytes.

**Golfed:**

```
DECLARE @i varchar(max)='*///*-*+-+'
,@ INT=0WHILE @i>''SELECT @+=CHOOSE(CHARINDEX(LEFT(@i,1),'+-*/'),1,-1,@,(@+ABS(@%2))/-2),@i=STUFF(@i,1,1,'')PRINT @
```

**Ungolfed:**

```
DECLARE @i varchar(max)='*///*-*+-+'

,@ INT=0
WHILE @i>''
  SELECT @+=CHOOSE(CHARINDEX(LEFT(@i,1),'+-*/'),1,-1,@,(@+ABS(@%2))/-2),
  @i=STUFF(@i,1,1,'')
PRINT @
```

**[Fiddle](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/545850/simple-integer-operation-calculator)**

Answer (score 0):

## MMIX, 64 bytes (16 instrs)

```
00000000: e3010000 f000000b 31ff022f 5aff0003  ẉ¢¡¡ṅ¡¡¿1”£/Z”¡¤
00000010: 3d010101 f0000007 31ff022a 5aff0003  =¢¢¢ṅ¡¡¬1”£*Z”¡¤
00000020: 39010101 f0000003 34ff2c02 200101ff  9¢¢¢ṅ¡¡¤4”,£ ¢¢”
00000030: 81ff0000 e7000001 5b02fff4 f8020000  ¹”¡¡ḃ¡¡¢[£”ṡẏ£¡¡
```

```
clc SET  $1,0           // acc = 0
    JMP  1F             // goto load
0H  CMP  $255,$2,'/'
    PBNZ $255,2F        // loop: if(c != '/') goto notdiv
    SR   $1,$1,1        // acc /= 2
    JMP  1F             // goto load
2H  CMP  $255,$2,'*'
    PBNZ $255,2F        // notdiv: if(c != '*') goto notmul
    SL   $1,$1,1        // acc *= 2
    JMP  1F             // goto load
2H  NEG  $255,',',$2
    ADD  $1,$1,$255     // notmul: acc += ',' - c
1H  LDB  $255,$0
    INCL $0,1           // load: c = *s++
    PBNZ $255,0B        // if(c) goto loop
    POP  2,0            // return acc
```

Answer (score 0):

## [Stax](https://github.com/tomtheisen/stax), 12 [bytes](https://github.com/tomtheisen/stax/blob/master/docs/packed.md#packed-stax)

```
î┴$'▌>bå╦♦\‼
```

[Run and debug it](https://staxlang.xyz/#p=8cc12427dd3e6286cb045c13&i=*%2F%2F%2F*-*%2B-%2B%0A%2F*%2B%2F*%2B%2B%2B%2F*%2F%2F%2F*%2F%2B-%2B%2F%2F*%2B-%2B-%2F----*-*-%2B%2B%2B*%2B**%2B%2F*--%2F%2F%2F%2B*-%2F%2B%2F%2F*%2F%2F-%2B%2B%2B--%2B%2B%2F-**--%2F%2B--%2F*-%2F%2B*%2F%2F*%2B-*-*%2F*%2B*%2B%2F%2B*-%0A%2B%2B%2B-%2B--%2F-*%2F---%2B%2B%2F-%2B*-%2F%2F%2B%2F%2B%2B-*--%2B*%2B%2F*%2F*%2F%2B%2B--%2B%2B-%2B%2F%2F%2B%2B--*%2F***-*%2B%2B%2B--%2B-*%2F%2F-*%2F%2B*%2F%2B-*%2B%2B**%2B--*%2F*%2F%2F-*--**-%2F-*%2B**-%2F*-**%2F*%2B*-*%2F--%2B%2F%2B%2F%2B%2F%2F-%2B*%2F---%2F%2F%2F%2B**%2F%2F%2F%2F-*%2F%2F%2B-%2B-%2F%2B--%2F**%2F%2F%2F*%2B%2F%2F%2B%2B%2B%2F%2B*%2B%2B**%2B%2B%2F%2F**%2B**%2B-*%2F%2B%2F*%2F*%2B%2B-%2F%2B**%2B--%2B*%2B%2B%2B%2B%2F-*-%2F*%2B--%2F%2B%2B*%2F-%2B%2B%2F-**%2B%2B%2B%2B%2F-%2F%2B%2F--*%2F-%2F%2B---**%2F%2F*%2F%2F%2F-%2F%2F*%2B-*----%2B%2F%2F--%2F-%2F%2B*%2F-%2B%2B%2B-%2B*-*%2B*%2B-%2F-%2F%2F*-%2F%2F%2B%2F*-%2B%2F%2F%2B%2F%2B%2F*-%2F-%2F%2B%2F%2F%2B**%2F-****%2F-**-%2F%2F%2B%2F%2B-%2B%2F*-%2B*%2B%2B*%2F-%2F%2B%2B*%2F-%2F%2F*--%2B*--%2F-%2B-%2B%2F%2B%2F**%2F-***%2B%2F-%2F%2B%2B-%2B%2B*%2B*-%2B*%2B*-%2B-%2F%2F%2B%2F-%2B%2B*%2B%2F*%2F%2F*-%2B%2F%2B*%2F-%2B%2F-%2F*%2F-%2F-%2B*%2B**%2F*%2F%2F*%2B%2F%2B---%2B*%2B%2B%2B*%2B%2F%2B-**%2F-%2B-%2F%2B*---%2F-*%2B%2F-%2B%2B*%2F%2F*%2F-%2B-*%2B--**%2F-%2F%2F%2F%2F*%2F--%2F*--%2F%2F-**%2F*%2B%2B*%2B%2F*%2B%2F-%2B%2F--**%2F*-%2B*%2B%2F%2B-*%2B*%2B--*%2F%2F%2F%2B-%2B%2B%2F%2B%2F%2F%2B*%2F-%2B%2F**--%2F%2F*%2F%2B%2B%2B%2F*%2B*%2F%2F%2F%2F%2B-*-%2F%2F--*%2B%2F*%2F-%2B**%2F*%2F%2F%2B*%2B-%2F%2F%2B--%2B*-%2B%2F-**-*%2F%2B%2F%2F*%2B---*%2B%2F%2F*%2F%2B**%2F*--%2F--%2B%2F*-*%2B*%2B%2B--*%2B%2F%2F%2B*%2B-%2B%2B--%2B-*-*-%2B--**%2B%2F%2B*-%2F%2B*%2B-%2F---%2B-*%2B-%2B-%2F%2B%2B%2F%2B*%2F%2F%2F*%2F*-%2B-*%2F%2F-%2B-%2B%2B%2F%2B%2B%2F*%2F-%2B%2B%2F**--%2B-%2F%2F%2F%2F-%2F%2F%2B%2F*%2F%2F%2B**%2F*%2B-%2B%2F%2B%2F%2B%2F%2F%2F*%2B*%2F%2F%2F*-%2F%2B%2F*%2F-%2F%2F-*-**%2F%2F-%2F-%2B--%2B%2F-*--%2B-%2B%2B**%2B%2B%2F%2F*--%2F*%2B%2B--*-%2F-%2F%2F%2F-%2B%2F%2B%2F%2F--%2B*%2F%2F-**-%2F*-*%2F%2B*%2F-*-*%2F%2F--%2B%2B*%2F%2F-*%2F%2B%2B%2F%2F%2B%2F-%2B%2B-%2B-*%2F*-%2B%2B%2B**-%2F-*%2B%2B%2B%2B**%2B-%2B%2B%2B-%2B-***-%2B%2F%2F%2B-%2F**-%2B%2F*%2B****-*%2B%2B%2B*%2F-*-%2F***%2F-%2F*%2B%2F*****%2B%2B*%2B%2F-%2F-**-%2B-*-*-%2B%2B**%2F*%2B-%2F*-%2B*%2B%2B-%2F%2B%2F-%2B%2B*-%2F*-****-*&m=2)

14 bytes unpacked.